# Trying to assign an extern __shared__ memory pointer leads to "expression must be a modifiable lvalue" error

Tags: cuda

I have something like the code below:

```
__device__ unsigned char* device_func(unsigned char* var_sh, unsigned char param){
    if (var_sh[0] == param)
        return var_sh + param;
    else return 0;
}

__global__ void global_func(uchar parameters){
    extern __shared__ unsigned char var_sh[];
    //just copying things from global to shared memory:
    for(int i = blockIndex; i < size; i += blockDim.x * gridDim.x){
        var_sh[i] = rla->initial[i]; 
    }
    var_sh = device_func(var_sh, parameters);
}
```

This global function is called in this way:

```
global_func<<< blocks,threads,shared_size >>>(parameters);
```

But when I try to compile, the compiler returns the following error on the line "var_sh = device_func(var_sh, parameters);":

"error: expression must be a modifiable lvalue"

I don't know why, can someone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we declare `__shared__` memory as `extern`, we need to assign this variable to a pointer before using it. In my problem i was using `var_sh` and trying to modify it, but first i need to assign it to a pointer and then use it like i want.

I've fixed my problem doing:

```
extern __shared__ uchar array[];
uchar* var_sh = (uchar*) array;
```

This way `var_sh` is a `modifiable lvalue` and i can use and modify it.

Answer (score 2):

This error means that the expression on the left of '=' can't be modified. In this case, var_sh has been defined, it is an unsigned char array, but in your code, you assign another pointer to var_sh: 'var_sh = device_func(var_sh, parameters)', it may point to another address, but not the shared memory.

Comment: But i'm returning a shared memory address. It's the original address + something. And i have the memory needed allocated.

Comment: In addition, can you tell me how to fix it? I need the data to be in shared memory because it is faster and the access to this data don't follow any pattern.

Comment: Your device_func may return 0, this is a integer, but var_sh is a pointer to the shared memory, so it may occur this error.

Comment: Just follow the example given in the [programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared) for creating arbitrary pointers based off an `extern` shared memory allocation.   Don't try to reassign `var_sh`, create a new pointer and set it to whatever value you want.

Comment: @RobertCrovella, i did what you said. The problem was with var_sh, i was using it in the way it come from the extern call. I've fixed doing: `extern __shared__ uchar array[];` and `uchar* aut_sh = (uchar*) array;`. This answer here is useful, but didn't helped me. So, could you answer it properly so i can check it as answered? Thanks.